# Access elements of an anonymous array via JsonPath in RestAssured

Tags: json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have an anonymous array in JSON returned from a service like:

```
[
  {"foo":1, "bar":2 , "baz":3 },
  {"foo":3, "bar":4 , "baz":5 }
]
```

How can I access the `bar` elements e.g. in

```
expect().body("$[*].bar", hasItems(2,4))
```

I tried a few possibilities that I found here and also on the [JsonPath page](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) by Stefan Gössner, but whatever I try I get exceptions. My issue seems to directly come from trying to access that list of items.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Given that you have:

```
[
  {"foo":1, "bar":2 , "baz":3 },
  {"foo":3, "bar":4 , "baz":5 }
]
```

You can do the following in Rest Assured:

```
then().body("bar",hasItems(2,4))
```

or

```
expect().body("bar",hasItems(2,4))
```

if you're using the legacy API.

Comment: I know it is not valid - that is why I wrote "pseudocode" in the first line of my question :-)

Answer (score 33):

Johan's answer is correct, just for the sake of completeness: An alternative way to check the 'bar' elements with rest-assured would be

```
expect().
    body("[0].bar", equalTo(2)).
    body("[1].bar", equalTo(4));
```

Comment: Just be careful with this - the order of elements may not always be the same.

Comment: That's right, that's the main reason for using "hasItems" in the first place - you use it in cases where you can't expect a specific (and fixed) order.

Comment: This is correct but if order gets change, it will surely fail.

Comment: maybe Hamcrest `containsInAnyOrder()` will help you... http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...)